# Typecasting IQueryable<T> to IOrderedQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable, .net-6.0

Does anyone know if there's any potential issues typecasting an `IQueryable<T>` to `IOrderedQueryable<T>`?

```
public IOrderedQueryable<T> ApplyFilter<T>(IOrderedQueryable<T> query)
{
    // NOTE: Skip() and Take() both return IQueryable<T>
    return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)query
        .Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize)
        .Take(PageSize);
}
```

Even though `IOrderedQueryable<T>` implements `IQueryable<T>` and not the other way around, `IOrderedQueryable<T>` has no members of its own. So it doesn't seem to matter and, in fact, appears to work.

But does it have the potential to cause problems? And, if so, is there another efficient way?

Comment: Any meaningful question about "good practices" must also include some statement about what "good practice" means in your question's context.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Does it have the potential to cause errors or other problems?

Comment: According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iorderedqueryable-1?view=net-6.0), *"This interface represents the result of a sorting query that calls the method(s) OrderBy, OrderByDescending, ThenBy or ThenByDescending. When CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression) is called and passed an expression tree that represents a sorting query, the resulting IQueryable<T> object must be of a type that implements IOrderedQueryable<T>."*

Comment: So it appears to function as a marker interface, of sorts.  Since you already have access to IEnumerable, which will already do the right thing, I'm not sure type casting to IOrderedEnumerable provides any benefit.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Casting an `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` is rarely the right thing to do - what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is conceptually a bad idea because it assumes `ApplyFilter` preserves the order of its input, but unless `ApplyFilter` explicitly takes an `IOrderedQueryable` (which seems unlikely) there's no reason to assume that. Ordering should ideally happen as the last step, and then it won't matter if the filter respects the order or not. If `ApplyFilter` *does* respect order it should have an overload that takes and returns an `IOrderedQueryable` to make that clear.

Comment: @NetMage: `ApplyFilter()` modifies an `IOrderedQueryable<T>` by calling `Skip()` and `Take()`, which unfortunately both return `IQueryable<T>`. I'm simply trying to return what I was given: An `IOrderedQueryable<T>`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Please see my answer to NetMage. I'll also update my question.

Comment: The reason adding further methods to the `IOrderedQueryable` converts to a `IQueryable` is so `ThenBy()` will not be valid. There is no purpose to casting back to `IOrderedQueryable`.